# simplify these jquery?

Tags: jquery

how can i simplify these jquery code? any idea?

```
   $('#expand').click(function() {
            $('.bbit-tree-elbow-plus').addClass('bbit-tree-elbow-minus');
            $('.bbit-tree-elbow-minus').removeClass('bbit-tree-elbow-plus');
            $('ul.bbit-tree-node-ct .bbit-tree-elbow-end-plus').addClass('bbit-tree-elbow-end-minus');
            $('ul.bbit-tree-node-ct .bbit-tree-elbow-end-minus').removeClass('bbit-tree-elbow-end-plus')
            if ($("#preview_root").hasClass("bbit-tree-node-collapsed")) {
                $('#preview_root').removeClass('bbit-tree-node-collapsed');
                $('#preview_root').addClass('bbit-tree-node-expanded');
                $('ul.bbit-tree-root .bbit-tree-elbow-end-plus').addClass('bbit-tree-elbow-end-minus');
                $('ul.bbit-tree-root .bbit-tree-elbow-end-minus').removeClass('bbit-tree-elbow-end-plus')
                $('.bbit-tree-node-ct').show();
            }
            $(".bbit-tree-node-ct ul").show();
        });
        $('#collapse').click(function() {
            $('.bbit-tree-elbow-minus').addClass('bbit-tree-elbow-plus');
            $('.bbit-tree-elbow-plus').removeClass('bbit-tree-elbow-minus');
            $('ul.bbit-tree-node-ct .bbit-tree-elbow-end-minus').addClass('bbit-tree-elbow-end-plus');
            $('ul.bbit-tree-node-ct .bbit-tree-elbow-end-plus').removeClass('bbit-tree-elbow-end-minus')
            $(".bbit-tree-node-ct ul").hide('slow');
        });
```

Comment: What should it be doing?

Comment: You would have to restructure the CSS so that you could just change a parent and have the rest of the children style correctly.  Can you post the CSS for these classes so that we can help?

Comment: html structure would much help us helping you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toggleClass` instead of addClass removeClass and put your class names in as arguments of the function.

[Toggle Class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use toggleClass as TALLBOY mentioned. Also, consider putting your $('.class') calls into a variable. For example:

```
var plus = $('.bbit-tree-elbow-plus');
```

from then on, use it like:

```
plus.toggleClass('bbit-tree-elbow-minus');
```